# jQuery make li active show div content

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I have a ul nav. I need to show div content when the "Resources" li is clicked and make "Resources" li active. Then when the div content is clicked to close, hide div content and make li not active. I'm not sure how to go about doing this so any insight would help.

Click this li item, make active:

```
<li><a href="">Resources</a></li>
```

Show this div content

```
<div id="pdftab">Some content</div>
```

Thanks so much

Comment: Does the `li` have an `id` at all? Is there any relationship between the the `li` element(s) and the order of the div(s)? Can you supply a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) showing a larger portion of your (representative) mark-up?

Comment: The li doesn't have an id. On this particular page there is only 2 lis. One goes to an external link. The "Resources" li will be the only li to show div content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having knowledge of your page markup I can just give you a hint. Something like this would work for you.

```
$('li a').click(function(){
   $('#pdftab').show();
   $(this).parent().addClass('active');
   return false;
});

$('#pdftab').click(function(){
   $(this).hide();
   $('li').removeClass('active');
});
```

Define the active class styles

```
.active{
   //add required styles
}
```

You can use `addClass`/`removeClass` to add/remove classes from dom elements. Calling `.parent()` on a jQuery object gets the parent element.

Update:

Based on your markup from

```
$('#navlist li:eq(1) a').click(function(){
   $('#pdftab').show()
               .animate({left: '+=340px'}, 1200);
   $(this).parent().addClass('resourceactive');
   return false;
});

$('#pdftab').click(function(){
   $(this).hide();
   $('#navlist li:eq(1)').removeClass('resourceactive');
});
```

Comment: If you click "Resources" while the content is out the content keeps on animating. Is there a function to stop the animation when you click on "Resources"?

Comment: That is because you are animating it with everytime you click on it. Replace this line `$('#pdftab').animate({left: '+=843px'}, 1200);` by `$('#pdftab').css('left', '0px').animate({left: '+=843px'}, 1200);` in your code.